# Schema for optional conditions in Joi

Tags: javascript, joi

Suppose I have an object like:

```
{
  a : 1,
  b : 2,
  c : 3,
  d : 4
}
```

**At least 1 of pair** out of `[a,b], [a,c], [d]` should have validation passed(have correct values).

Assume all values are **numbers**.

How can I create Joi schema for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Joi.alternatives()** and create a Joi schema like this:

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object({
        a: Joi.number().required(),
        b: Joi.number().required(),
        c: Joi.number(),
        d: Joi.number()
    }),
    Joi.object({
        a: Joi.number().required(),
        b: Joi.number(),
        c: Joi.number().required(),
        d: Joi.number()
    }),
    Joi.object({
        a: Joi.number(),
        b: Joi.number(),
        c: Joi.number(),
        d: Joi.number().required()
    }),
)
```

There is another alternative that uses **.requiredKeys()** and simplies the code above :

```
const JoiObjectKeys = {
    a: Joi.number(),
    b: Joi.number(),
    c: Joi.number(),
    d: Joi.number()
}

Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object(JoiObjectKeys).requiredKeys('a', 'b'),
    Joi.object(JoiObjectKeys).requiredKeys('a', 'c'),
    Joi.object(JoiObjectKeys).requiredKeys('d'),
);
```

With this schema you will get this results:

```
{ a: 1 } > fails
{ b: 1 } > fails
{ c: 1 } > fails
{ a: 1, b: 1 } > passes
{ a: 1: c: 1 } > passes
{ d: 1 } > passes
{ d: 1, a: 1 } > passes
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with using `Joi.number()`. It will also consider `'3'` to be valid — without actually turning it into the number `3` if you're using `Joi.assert`. To avoid that, you should probably add the `.strict()` modifier.

See https://medium.com/east-pole/surprised-by-joi-35a3558eda30